# Global vars in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I have two NodeJS Files:

#### main.js:

```
global.clients = [];

const net       = require('net');
const ki        = require('./keyboard_interface.js');

net.createServer(function (socket)
{
    // Put this new client in the list
    clients.push(socket);
});
```

#### keyboard_interface.js:

```
var readline = require('readline');
var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
  terminal: false
});

rl.on('line', function(line)
{
        if (line == 'c')
        {
                console.log('----Connected Clients----');
                clients.forEach(function (socket)
                {
                            console.log(socket.name);
                });
        }
});
```

I have verified that the clients array is filled with content, I can access the clients variable from `keyboard_interface.js`, but why is it empty?

Answer (score 0):

Use `global.clients` to access the array in `keyboard_interface.js`

Comment: it is also empty

Comment: I missed.  Use `global.clients` in `main.js` too.